# Reminder to check in on TFS before Queue New Build

Tags: version-control, build, tfs, msbuild

This trips up a lot of newcomers to TFS, and I'm keen to hear your solutions.

So you've fixed a bug, tested it, looks good, everyone is on top of you to get it out as soon as possible, so you queue a new remote build, wait patiently, then put it into test/production only to find out it's actually an old version - you forgot to check in before doing the build!!

OK, so this is a common oversight, and it costs valuable time. Is it possible to pop up a warning first, or is there some neat trick other have found to avoid this?

Answer (score 2):

Instead of manually kicking off a build after you check-in, what if you set up a "Continuous Integration" build so that the build would be automatically kicked off once you checked in?  This way it would be impossible to forget to check in your changes.  Here is an article on how you can set that up:  http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb668971.aspx.

Comment: Thanks Taylor, we are moving towards that... albeit slowly. It's just some of our 'greener' guys are wasting hours forgetting to check in!

Comment: Although I'd say it's a bad idea to implement CI for a production environment/build.

Answer (score 0):

Continous Integration as mentioned above is the best solution! :)

But you could write a custom activity within your build definition to check if there were any new changesets since the last build and if there is no new changeset show a warning message in the build log or something, but then again the developer has to read to log otherwise it's not useful.

I wouldnt spend any time at all for something like this, I would rather knock on the developers head everytime he misses the check-in! :}